# Condensing an if-statement

Tags: python, list, operator-keyword

I have the following lists:

```
languages =["java", "haskell", "Go", "Python"]
animals = ["pigeon", "python", "shark"]
names = ["Johan","Frank", "Sarah"]
```

I want to find out whether or not python exists in all three of the following lists. The following if-statement is what I came up with just using the "in" method and "and" operators.

```
if("Python" in languages and "Python" in animals and "Python" in names )
```

Is there a way to condense this statement into a smaller length? 
 I.E.

```
if("Python" in languages and in animals and in names)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can avoid repeating `"Python"`:

```
if all("Python" in L for L in [languages, animals, names]):
```

But this is not much shorter.

Comment: Is there a way to use a method within that? i.e. the comparison of "python" to L.lower() ?

Comment: Yes, the part `"Python" in L` can be replaced with `"python" in L.lower()` or any expression although some of them require enclosing parentheses or brackets.

Answer (score 5):

If this is a test you're expecting to do repeatedly, it would be more efficient to pre-calculate the intersection of your lists:

```
lanimes = set(languages) & set(animals) & set(names)

if "Python" in lanimes:
```

(The `in` operator is O(n) for a list, O(1) for a set.)

Comment: Would make total sense for an often-repeated operation. For a one-off check, building the sets would take longer than the full scans of the lists for checking.

Comment: I got `lanimes` as `set()`. And it's has to check in each list.

Comment: @RahulKP: yes, an empty set is expected here, as the sample lists contain no elements in common.

Answer (score 4):

Consider:

```
if all("Python" in x for x in (languages, animals, names)):
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Python has any syntax sugar specifically like that, but depending on how many lists you have, you could do something like

```
if all("Python" in x for x in [languages, animals, names])
```

On its own, it's probably a bit more verbose than your `and`s, but if you have a large number of lists, or you already have a list of lists, then it should save some space, and IMHO it is more immediately clear what the goal of the if statement is.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Python 3, you can use [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/):

`if 'Python' in (*languages, *animals, *names):`

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No, the language syntax does not allow this.

If you *really* want to cut down on duplicating `'Python'`, you could use something like this in your if condition:

```
all('Python' in p for p in (languages, animal, names))
```

I also suggest that maybe you could reevaluate the design to make your code more flexible. Comprehensions and generator expressions are a good start.